# ALM JIRA Integration

Tags: jira, alm

I have created a link between ALM and JIRA to sync defects from ALM to JIRA. The integrity check passed and after enabling and trying to sync, am getting the following error,

05/22/2017,02:27:31,654 INFO (Create.From1To2.Source-1) Synchronize: JIRA: Creating new issue
05/22/2017,02:27:32,874 INFO (Create.From1To2.Source-1) Synchronize: JIRA: refreshing the issue id:26906
05/22/2017,02:27:32,925 INFO (Create.From1To2.Source-1) Synchronize: JIRA: Updating issue id:26906
05/22/2017,02:27:33,494 ERROR (Create.From1To2.Source-1) Create: Fatal exception caught,operation terminated. Cause: create: fatal error update: fatal error {"errorMessages":["one of 'fields' or 'update' required"],"errors":{}}
05/22/2017,02:27:33,499 INFO (Disconnection.Adapter1) DisconnectAdapter: Disconnecting adapter HPE-ALM
05/22/2017,02:27:33,499 INFO (Disconnection.Adapter1) DisconnectAdapter: HPE-ALM: disconnect() called
05/22/2017,02:27:33,502 INFO (Disconnection.Adapter1) DisconnectAdapter: HPE-ALM: Call to disconnect
05/22/2017,02:27:34,550 INFO (Disconnection.Adapter1) DisconnectAdapter: HPE-ALM: Call to logout

Not sure what this really means as am relatively new to both products. Could anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue with **26906** ID have some required fields.
You can figure out what this issue is via this URL: `http://your-jira-server/rest/api/2/issue/26906`. If you know the project of this issue and know which fields are required, this could already help.

If this information won't help you to figure out the actual reason of error, you can check which fields are actually required using this URL: `http://your-jira-server/rest/api/2/issue/26906/editmeta`. This should return you a JSON object, containing metadata about fields of given issue. Search for `"required": true` (or use jq utility) and figure out which fields are missing.

If the import failing during issue creation, you can try another URL: `http://your-jira-server/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectK‌​eys=~PROJECT_KEY~&is‌​suetypeNames=~ISSUE_‌​TYPE_NAME~&expand=pr‌​ojects.issuetypes.fi‌​elds` which will give you JSON metadata for creating new issue. Using this information, you can check whether some of the fields are missing in the source data.

Comment: Thank you but When I try that api, I get the following json reply,

{"errorMessages":["Issue Does Not Exist"],"errors":{}}

Comment: Well, then it looks like it tries to create new issue. Is **id** is different each time? Then you can try `http://your-jira-server/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=~PROJECT_KEY~&issuetypeNames=~ISSUE_TYPE_NAME~&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields` URL and check which fields are required for creation. If some are missing from ALM, you have to add them or make those fields not required.

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      <status>
<status-code>404</status-code>
<message>null for uri: http://<JIRA-Server>/rest/api/2/issue/26906/createmeta</message>
</status>

This is what I get, not sure why..

Comment: Please, refer to this page: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-discovering-meta-data-for-creating-issues
And I've updated the url, please use updated, withoud **id**.

Comment: Thank you. There is a mandatory field in JIRA called project that is not visible on the ALM JIRA synchronizer even after schema refresh

Comment: @MalaKannan, great. If you like my answer you can accept it and vote for it.

Comment: Oh that field in JIRA called project is auto populated by default. The issue by itself is not getting created. I have mapped all mandatory fields but still am facing the same above error that I started this thread with. Is there anything else that am missing or I need to check?

Comment: Searching for the error message in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=%22one+of+%27fields%27+or+%27update%27+required%22&oq=%22one+of+%27fields%27+or+%27update%27+required%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i71k1l3.0.0.0.2141.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.serp..0.0.0.ehucTzoH9ts), you will see that people complaining on issue update. Can you check, whether some of the issues in you project were created during import?
Also, if you have an access to JIRA logs you can check'em, as extended error message could be there.